# Organizando código dento do __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tendo dificuldade em organizar meu código.
Ex: Gostaria de colocar funções genéricas, como pro exemplo as que lidam com a leitura de um arquivo de configuração em apenas um lugar (li que o `__init__.py` é perfeito para isso). Entretanto, não consigo.

Esta é a atual organização do meu código:

```
├── nome_projeto
│   ├── nome_projeto.py
│   ├── config.ini
│   ├── database.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

Este é o conteúdo do meu `__init__.py`, que inclui as configurações de log, do arquivo de configuração e também uma função que retorna um parâmetro do arquivo de configuração.

```
"""Funções básicas usadas pelo programa"""


import os
import logging
import pathlib
import datetime
import configparser

#   Arquivo de configuração
CONFIG_FILE = 'config.ini'
CONFIG_PATH = ''.join([str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent), '/', CONFIG_FILE])

if os.path.exists(CONFIG_PATH):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(CONFIG_PATH)
else:
    logging.error(f'Conf file not found: {CONFIG_FILE}')


#   Cria diretório temporário se não existir
try:
    if not os.path.exists(config['DEFAULT']['TempDir']):
        #   Temp dir
        os.makedirs(config['DEFAULT']['TempDir'])

    if not os.path.exists(config['DEFAULT']['Log']):
        #   Verifica se existe, se não, cria
        log_file = open(config['DEFAULT']['Log'])
        log_file.write(f"Created at {str(datetime.datetime.today())}")
        log_file.close()
    elif not os.access(config['DEFAULT']['Log'], os.W_OK):
        #   Verifica se tem permissão de escrita
        logging.error(f"No permision to write: {config['DEFAULT']['Log']}")

except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f'Fail during creation: {e}')


#   Log
log_format = '%(asctime)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename=config['DEFAULT']['Log'],
                    format=log_format, level=logging.DEBUG)


def get_conf(param):
    """Retorna parametro"""
    return config['CONF'][param]
```

E aqui esta um dos arquivos do meu projeto que usaria a função `get_config`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Database access.
"""

import pymysql
import logging
from . import get_conf
from pymysql import Error


def connect():
    """Abre coneção"""
    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(host=get_conf('Address'),
                                     user=get_conf('DatabaseUser'),
                                     password=get_conf('DatabasePassword'),
                                     db=get_conf('Database'),
                                     charset='utf8mb4')
    except Error as e:
        logging.error(e)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return connection, cursor


def close(connection):
    """Commita e fecha coneção"""
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()


def lookup(option, tell):
    """ Recebe uma opção e o telefone.
    Retorna ou a senha, ou a contrasenha baseado na opção.
    """
    try:
        connection, cursor = connect()
        if option == 'pass':
            col = 'password_col_name'
        else:
            col = 'counter_password_col_name'
        cursor.execute(f"""
            SELECT {col} FROM table_name WHERE col_phone_number = {tell};
        """)
        return cursor.fetchone()
    except Error as e:
        logging.error(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Caso seja executado sozinho"""
    print(f"""
    Database: \t\t{get_conf('Database')}
    Address: \t\t{get_conf('Address')}
    Database User: \t{get_conf('DatabaseUser')}
    Database Password: \t{get_conf('DatabasePassword')}
    """)
```

Primeiro eu gostaria de entender se o que estou tentando fazer esta certo. Eu deveria armazenar esse tipo de coisa dentro do `__init__.py`? E eu também gostaria de tentar entender porque não estou conseguindo usar a função, já que estou importando com o ., e só consigo uma mensagem de erro ´´´ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package´´´?

Comment: A PAthlib é pra facilitar a vida, e não complicar - em vez de `CONFIG_PATH = ''.join([str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent), '/', CONFIG_FILE])` é só colocar `CONFIG_PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / CONFIG_FILE ` - não precisa transformar em string, e aí usar funcionalidades de string para juntar as partes.

Comment: E ai, o CONFIG_PATH, sendo um objeto  `Path` , e não uma string, já tem o método `exists` direto:  `if CONFIG_PATH.exists(): ` - a pathlib veio para juntar várias funcionalidades de arqiuvo que estavam espalhadas na biblioteca padrão - inclusive "read" e "write".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá -

de fato, o que vai dentro do `__init__` pode ser um pouco coringa.

Se o projeto for uma biblioteca - com a ideia de ser importado e usado
por outros projetos, o melhor a fazer é deixar as classes
e funções públicas - ou pelo menos as que vão ser usadas na maioria das vezes
por quem for usar seu projeto, expostas no `__init__.py`. 
Um projeto em que eu invisto bastante nisso é na minha biblioteca [terminedia](https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/blob/master/terminedia/__init__.py).

Não significa que precisamos declarar essas funcionalidades lá  - e em geral
não devemos - apenas fazer o import delas lá no 
arquivo `__init__.py` no ponto certo, deixa elas visíveis.

Para projetos que são a aplicação final, como um serviço
(web ou outro), ou um app de desktop  - 
aí você pode deixar o que for conveniente no `__init__.py` ou
quebrar como quiser.

Tem que lembrar de  uma coisa: se o `__init__` importa os outros
módulos da sua aplicação, e os comandos de `import` estão no começo do 
arquivo, quando os outros módulos forem carregados, as funções e
variáveis definidas no `__init__` ainda não foram criados. Ou seja,
pode-se cair num problema de importações circulares, e o projeto não vai funcionar.

Algumas coisas de configuração como no exemplo que você deu, podem ficar lá -
mas sem precisar, não é legal deixar
código "solto" no corpo do módulo - melhor organizar em uma função, e chamar ela.

(E aí, se for o caso, você pode colocar a chamada dentro de um `if __name__ == "__main__":` que faz com que seu projeto, sem nenhum outro código, possa ser uma aplicação stand-alone ou uma biblioteca):

```py
"""Funções básicas usadas pelo programa"""

import os
import logging
import datetime
import configparser
from pathlib import Path

#   Arquivo de configuração
CONFIG_FILE = 'config.ini'
CONFIG_PATH = Path(__file__) / CONFIG_FILE

if CONFIG_PATH.exists():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(CONFIG_PATH)
else:
    logging.error(f'Conf file not found: {CONFIG_FILE}')


#   Log
log_format = '%(asctime)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename=config['DEFAULT']['Log'],
                    format=log_format, level=logging.DEBUG)

def prepare_files():
    #   Cria diretório temporário se não existir
    try:
        if not (tmpdir:= Path(config['DEFAULT']['TempDir'])).exists():
            # (acima o operador da "Morsa" (Walrus) - cria a variável
            # dentro da expressão de um if, economizando uma linha.
            # Requer Python 3.8
            # )
            #   Temp dir
            tmpdir.mkdir(parents=True)

        if not (log_path:=Path(config['DEFAULT']['Log'])).exists():
            log_path.write_text(f"Created at {str(datetime.datetime.today())}\n")
            # write_text já abre o arquivo, escreve a string, e fecha.
        elif not os.access(log_path, os.W_OK):
            #   Verifica se tem permissão de escrita
            logging.error(f"No permision to write: {log_path}")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Fail during creation: {e}')

prepare_files()

def get_conf(param):
    """Retorna parametro"""
    return config['CONF'][param]
```

Quanto ao seu erro:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Então - isso acontece por que você deve estar *dentro* do mesmo diretório onde está o `__init__.py` e tentando executar o arquivo `database.py` direto daí.

Se você mudar para o diretório onde está o `setup.py` e digitar `python nome_projeto/database.py` esse mesmo `import` vai funcionar.

Acontece que importações relativas usando "." ou ".." como prefixo de nomes de módulo só funcionam se o arquivo que faz os "import" estiver no mesmo pacote (package)  que o arq ele importa.  E para o Python "saber" que está no mesmo pacote, ele *tem* que chamar antes o `__init__.py` do mesmo diretório, e tem que ser chamado "de fora" da pasta "nome_projeto".

Só que para "chamar" não adianta escrever `python nome_projeto` ou `python -m nome_projeto` - nenhuma dessas duas formas executa primeiro o `__init__.py`. Para isso funcionar é preciso criar também um arquivo `__main__.py` - (que pode ser vazio) - aí você pode rodar seu projeto todo como um módulo, usando a opção -m (`python -m nome_projeto`) - o Python então carrega o `__init__.py`, executa ele todo, e em seguida, executa o arquivo `__main__.py`. Se quier rodar o `database.py` ou outro arquivo, precisa que ele seja importado de um desses dois arquivos - e aí sim, o `database.py`será reconhecido como "estou dentro de um pacote" - e vai poder ter a importação relativa como você escreveu.

Sem o arquivo `__main__.py` seu projeto já pode ser importado por outros pacotes, e o `__init__` vai funcionar - você pode executr um Python interativo na pasta onde está o setup.py, e usar `import nome_projeto`, por exemplo. Mas para ser chamado direto da linha de comando, é necessário o arquivo `__main__.py`.

Então é isso - só tomar cuidado para evitar importações circulares no `__init__` como escrevi acima - pode colocar um `import` para cada um dos outros arquivos no final do `__init__` (assim, quando eles forem chamados, a função `get_conf` já vai estar definida:

`__init__.py`:

```py
import datetime
...
def get_conf(conf):
   ...

from . import database, nome_projeto
```

database.py:

```py
...
from . import get_conf
...
```

Comment: Adicionei um link para o `__init__.py` de um projeto meu.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Ficou muito mais claro. Obrigado pelo exemplo também.